# How to split a string to multiple arrays based on multiple separators in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

**I have seen the questions but none of them helped me.
I have a string like this:**

var Lang_Array1 = "HU,blah,blah,blah,EN,blah,blah,blah,blah,DE,blah,blah,blah,RO,blah,blah,blah";

I want that string to be in different arrays based on the separators **"HU", "EN", "DE", "RO"**.

**My approach currently is this**(*Working but not too elegant*):

```
var Lang_Array1 = Lang_Array.split(",");
    console.log(typeof(Lang_Array));
    console.log(Lang_Array);

    var HU_Langs = [];
    var EN_Langs = [];
    var DE_Langs = [];
    var RO_Langs = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < Lang_Array1.length;i++){
        if(Lang_Array1[i] != "EN"){
            if(Lang_Array1[i] != ""){
                HU_Langs[i] = Lang_Array1[i];
            }
        }else{
            for(i;i < Lang_Array1.length;i++){
                if(Lang_Array1[i] != "DE"){
                    if(Lang_Array1[i] != ""){
                        EN_Langs[i] = Lang_Array1[i];
                    }
                }else{
                    for(i;i < Lang_Array1.length;i++){
                        if(Lang_Array1[i] != "RO"){
                            if(Lang_Array1[i] != ""){
                                DE_Langs[i] = Lang_Array1[i];
                            }
                        }else{
                            for(i;i < Lang_Array1.length;i++){
                                    if(Lang_Array1[i] != ""){
                                        RO_Langs[i] = Lang_Array1[i];
                                    }       
                                }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

**That way i get what i want but i want to improve it somehow.
The arrays:**

```
HU_Langs =["HU","blah","blah","blah"];
EN_Langs =["EN","blah","blah","blah"];
DE_Langs =["DE","blah","blah","blah"];
```

etc...

So how can i improve this code without nested for loops?

**EDIT:** *Thank you for all! All the answers are very very good.
My question wasnt clear and detailed enough but i solved it like this with the help of the correct answer.*

**Here is the function now:**

```
function Get_Language_Object(Lang_Array){
    Lang_Array = Lang_Array.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
    var langs = ['HU', 'EN', 'DE', 'RO'];
    var isLang = str => langs.includes(str);
    var { HU: New_HU_Langs, EN: New_EN_Langs, DE: New_DE_Langs, RO: New_RO_Langs } = Lang_Array.split(',')
        .reduce((r, str) => {
    if(isLang(str)) r.push([]);
        r[r.length - 1].push(str);
        return r;
    }, [])
        .reduce((r, [code, ...arr]) => ({ ...r, [code]: arr }), {});
    for(var i = 0; i < TAGS.length;i++){
        arrLang.HU[TAGS[i]] = New_HU_Langs[i];
        arrLang.EN[TAGS[i]] = New_EN_Langs[i];
        arrLang.DE[TAGS[i]] = New_DE_Langs[i];
        arrLang.RO[TAGS[i]] = New_RO_Langs[i];
    }
    Set_Actual_Language();
    VNotify("Settings Notfy","Lang Set!","success",1500,"success32.png");
}
```

Comment: If your code is working but you want to improve it, then this question is for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not for StackOverflow

Comment: Wouldn't you just split on comma and read each token until you hit a new LANG type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the string by the delimiter (`,`), reduce the array, and for every language code, add a new sub-array. Push all items to the last sub-array:

```js
var Lang_Array1 = "HU,blah,blah,blah,EN,blah,blah,blah,blah,DE,blah,blah,blah,RO,blah,blah,blah";

var langs = ['HU', 'EN', 'DE', 'RO'];

var isLang = str => langs.includes(str);

var result = Lang_Array1.split(',')
  .reduce((r, str) => {
    if(isLang(str)) r.push([]);
    
    r[r.length - 1].push(str);
  
    return r;
  }, []);
  
console.log(result);
```

If you want to split to multiple arrays, reduce the sub-arrays to an object, and use desturcturing to assign them to variables:

```js
var Lang_Array1 = "HU,blah,blah,blah,EN,blah,blah,blah,blah,DE,blah,blah,blah,RO,blah,blah,blah";

var langs = ['HU', 'EN', 'DE', 'RO'];

var isLang = str => langs.includes(str);

var { HU: HU_Langs, EN: EN_Langs, DE: DE_langs, RO: RO_langs } = Lang_Array1.split(',')
  .reduce((r, str) => {
    if(isLang(str)) r.push([]);
    
    r[r.length - 1].push(str);
  
    return r;
  }, [])
  .reduce((r, [code, ...arr]) => ({ ...r, [code]: arr }), {});
  
console.log(HU_Langs, EN_Langs, DE_langs, RO_langs);
```

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't clear. I want to split it to multiple arrays, i edited my post.

like this:
HU_Langs =["HU","blah","blah","blah"];
EN_Langs =["EN","blah","blah","blah"];
DE_Langs =["DE","blah","blah","blah"];

Comment: Thank you very much! You second comment is working perfectly.Hovewer the first is the best because i would improve my implementation further withyour help.
The thing is that your first answer is better for me just not in that way. I have all the languages inside an object and i would be able to skip 1-2 steps from this code:

Comment: Oh can't insert the code in here because its too long. :(

Comment: Create a jsfiddle/codepen/etc... and post the link in the comments.

Comment: I updated my post but i uploaded it to pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/iFBjPa9w

Answer (score 0):

You should reduce the list of words after splitting on your delimiter (`,`). Each time you run into a known key, you alter the `key` that refers to the current language.

This is the most succinct example:

```js
let arr = "HU,blaf,blaf,blaf,EN,blah,blah,blah,blah,DE,bla,bla,bla,RO,bah,bah,bah"
let keys = [ "DE", "EN", "HU", "RO" ]
let dict = langDict(arr, keys)

console.log(dict)

function langDict(arr, keys) {
  let key = null
  return arr.split(/,/g).reduce((dict, token) => {
    if (Object.keys(dict).length && key == null) {
      throw new Error('No language defined yet!')
    } else if (keys.includes(token)) {
      key = token
    } else {
      if (dict[key] == null) dict[key] = []
      dict[key].push(token)
    }
    return dict
  }, {})
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I believe the upper case ISO2 code is the language hint, you could group all results together in a more scalable way.

```
var Lang_Array1 = "HU,blah,blah,blah,EN,blah,blah,blah,blah,DE,blah,blah,blah,RO,blah,blah,blah";
var Languages = {};
var current = '';

Lang_Array1.split(',').forEach(function (value) {
  if (/^[A-Z]{2}$/.test(value))
    current = value;
  else
    Languages[current] = (Languages[current] || []).concat(value);
});

console.log(Languages);
```

Above snippet would populate the `Languages` object like this:

```
{
  "HU": [
    "blah",
    "blah",
    "blah"
  ],
  "EN": [
    "blah",
    "blah",
    "blah",
    "blah"
  ],
  "DE": [
    "blah",
    "blah",
    "blah"
  ],
  "RO": [
    "blah",
    "blah",
    "blah"
  ]
}
```

At this point, all you have to do is to address directly `Languages.EN` or others, or recreate the original structure via:

```
var Lang_Array = Object.keys(Languages).reduce(
  function (arr, key) {
    return arr.concat(key, Languages[key]);
  },
  []
);
```

You could also create arrays with the language starting at index 0, and values following:

```
var Lang_EN = ['EN'].concat(Languages.EN);
```

As summary, grouping by keys seem the best way to represent, and manipulate, such flattened structure.

I hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

If the order is constant:

```
var Lang_Array1 = "HU,blah1,blah2,blah3,EN,blah4,blah5,blah6,blah7,DE,blah8,blah9,blah10,RO,blah11,blah12,blah13";
const arr1 = Lang_Array1.split(/[HU,EN,DE,RO]/g);
let obj = {hu:[],en:[],de:[],ro:[]};
const keys = Object.keys(obj);
let i = 0;
arr1.forEach(el=>{
    if(el !== '')
      obj[ keys[i] ].push(el);
  else
    if(obj[ keys[i] ].length > 0)
      i++;
 });

console.log(obj);
```

Response:

```
{hu: Array(3), en: Array(4), de: Array(3), ro: Array(3)}
hu: (3) ["blah1", "blah2", "blah3"]
en: (4) ["blah4", "blah5", "blah6", "blah7"]
de: (3) ["blah8", "blah9", "blah10"]
ro: (3) ["blah11", "blah12", "blah13"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporary array can be used to reference the array to push to :

```js
var Lang_Array = "HU,blah,blah,blah,EN,blah,blah,blah,blah,DE,blah,blah,blah,RO,blah,blah,blah";
var Lang_Array1 = Lang_Array.split(","), HU_Langs = [], EN_Langs = [], DE_Langs = [], RO_Langs = [];

for (var Langs = [], i = 0; i < Lang_Array1.length; i++)
{
  var str = Lang_Array1[i];

  Langs = { HU: HU_Langs, EN: EN_Langs, DE: DE_Langs, RO: RO_Langs }[str] || Langs;

  Langs.push(str);
}

console.log( HU_Langs, EN_Langs, DE_Langs, RO_Langs );
```